# Windows Phone 10 emulator doesn't shows maps

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10, uwp

When placing a map control (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl) on a page and opening it, the windows phone 10 emulator shows a blank map. Actually it's blue :P
The same thing happens when opening the maps application inside the emulator.

**Edit:**
I'm able to access the internet from within the emulator (perform http requests, open pages in edge, etc.), so it's not a connectivity problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoding to this Microsoft link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526491

> When you include the Windows 10 **MapControl** (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps) in your XAML-based app, it does not render maps on Windows 10 phone emulators. A blank, blue map appears without any map tiles. The map renders fine in on a physical phone device.
>   **Workaround:** Use a physical phone device to test the map, or continue to use it in a desktop environment. This issue will be fixed in the next public release of the SDK.